# Open Source USB Gateway like USB for USB port forwarding between Linux Machines?

Tags: linux, open-source, usb

Is there an open source USB Gateway software for Linux that will forward USB ports to another machine on the network, or even a virtual machine instead of the thin client?

Comment: What kind of virtual machine you're talking about? Software like VirtualBox (which has a FOSS variant shipping with most Linux distris) can do that themselves.

Comment: @aizzy Accross a network?

Comment: How about just to another machine; doesn't have to be a VM.

Comment: I don't know – but maybe you [edit] your question to improve your specification? As it's currently phrased, it's hard to understand: what VM, what thin client, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @aizzy Is that better?

Comment: Yes – now you'd only need to specify what "the thin client" is – we don't see the context you are in. Maybe you mean "or even a VM *on the same client"* here? Could you describe your situation/environment so we can understand it? Are you looking for something like [Using a remote host's USB port as local USB (Linux and Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18837277/2533433) // [Linux usb device forwarding](https://serverfault.com/q/248378/145213)?

Comment: @Izzy Oh I see, I'm looking for Linux to Linux actual; who would want to pay for Windows?

Comment: Second link then. And again: to get any good recommendations here, consider [edit]ing your question and describe a bit of the background, what you want to achieve. For example (and not to be taken literally): "My USB-Vibrator is connected to a RasPi, but I want to control it from my Laptop …" :P // It's still not clear what a [thin client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_client) has to do with it.